# With a MySQL Query, If a Field has a particular value, then include it in the SELECT query otherwise, don't include it

Tags: mysql

I have a query and I want to include a particular field in the query, but only if that field has a particular value in it, otherwise, I don't want to include it.

So, for example if my table has:

```
 ID     |     Title     |     Liked     |     Score

 1         Happy Song           1             10
 2         Sad Song             0             20
 3         Fun Song             1             30
 4       Friendly Song          0             15
```

My initial query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM songs 
WHERE Liked = '1' 
ORDER BY ID Score DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

However, IF none of the records returned had a 1 in the Liked field or only one of them did, I STILL need three records returned and want it to just return regular non-Liked records.

Is this possible?

Comment: FYI, you're missing a comma between `ID, Score`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM songs
ORDER BY Liked DESC, ID, Score DESC
LIMIT 3
```

`ORDER BY Liked DESC` puts the liked records first. If there are at least 3 liked records, they will be shown. If there are fewer, it will add non-liked records.

BTW, if the `ID` field is unique, there's no point in having other fields after it in the `ORDER BY` clause. Later fields are only used when earlier fields have the same value. You probably want `ORDER BY Liked DESC, Score DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY Liked DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 3;
```

You need to order by Liked column as well, to get the top 3 liked IDs.

Comment: You need to order by `Liked` first.